# Is this legit?: "What is the probability that Hugo buys at most 3 packs of cards?"

Tags: word-choice

## Citation from [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/random-variables-discrete/e/probability-discrete-random-variables):

#### Problem sentence:

> Hugo plans to buy packs of baseball cards until he gets the card of
> his favorite player, but he only has enough money to buy at most 4
> packs. Suppose that each pack has probability 0.2 of containing the
> card Hugo is hoping for.

> *< The probability information in a table comes here >*

#### Question sentence

> **What is the probability that Hugo buys at most 3 packs of cards?**

## My question:

Is the above question sentence correct and natural?
I think the following sentence, which I rephrased the question sentence to, is more natural to me.

> **What is the probability that Hugo buys 3 or less packs of cards?**

Answer (score 1):

> **What is the probability that Hugo buys at most 3 packs of cards?**

sounds good.

---

> What is the probability that Hugo buys 3 or less packs of cards?

This sounds awkward (Order of adjectives). Think about buying a piece of cloth or some vegetables.

You would buy less than a meter or more than a meter of cloth. but not a meter less or a meter more as it would alter the meaning of the sentence.

You could buy just less than a pound of tomatoes or just more than a pound but not a pound less or a pound more.

---

To use less in this sentence try this

***>What is the probability that Hugo buys less than 3 packs of cards?***

**However this is now mathematically incorrect**

---

***>What is the probability that Hugo buys less than 4 packs of cards?***

sounds better, but is still mathematically incorrect as he could theoretically buy 3.5 packs. therefore the correct statement would be

**>What is the probability that Hugo buys at most three packs of cards?**

Comment: Order of adjectives. size comes before Purpose or qualifier. In this instance 3 packs is the qualifier. Hope this helps. https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/

Answer (score 1):

The following is natural sounding to mathematicians.
However, it does not sound natural to anyone besides a mathematician:

> What is the probability that Hugo buys ***at most*** 3 packs of cards?

The following is wrong:

> What is the probability that Hugo buys 3 or ***less*** packs of cards?

There are two words in English which have almost the same meaning:

1. "LESS"
2. "FEWER"

Consider nouns like "*card*"

If it is okay English to use a letter "s" at the end of word `X`, then write "*FEWER* `[X]s`"

If it is **NOT** correct English to use a letter "s" at the end of word `X`, then write "*LESS* `[X]`"

| Noun without "s" | Noun without "s" | Is the "s" okay? | "Less" or "fewer" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| information | informations | "s" at the end is *WRONG* | Less Information |
| patience | patiences | "s" at the end is *WRONG* | Less Patience |
| singing | singings | "s" at the end is *WRONG* | Less Singing |
| fishing | fishings | "s" at the end is *WRONG* | Less Fishing |
| butter | butters | "s" at the end is *WRONG* | Less Butter |
| air | airs | "s" at the end is *WRONG* |  |
| helium | heliums | "s" at the end is *WRONG* |  |
| petrol | petrols | "s" at the end is *WRONG* |  |
| concrete | concretes | "s" at the end is *WRONG* |  |
| gravity | gravities | "s" at the end is *WRONG* |  |
| thunder | thunders | "s" at the end is *WRONG* | Less Thunder |
| car | cars | "s" at the end is *okay* | Fewer Cars |
| card | cards | "s" at the end is *okay* | Fewer Cards |
| house | houses | "s" at the end is *okay* | Fewer Houses |
| computer | computers | "s" at the end is *okay* | Fewer Computers |

The best way to word your sentence is as one of the following:

> - What is the probability that Hugo buys 3 or fewer packs of cards?
> - What is the probability that Hugo buys 1, 2, or 3 packs of cards, or none at all?

Comment: I totally disagree with your statement about mathematicians. Take the sentence "until now, you could book *at most four months* in advance". https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-most ......... The sentence *"What is the probability that Hugo buys 3 or fewer packs of cards?"* is also incorrect and should be **What is the probability that Hugo buys fewer than 3 packs of cards?** and *"What is the probability that Hugo buys 1, 2, or 3 packs of cards, or none at all?"* Is both mathematically different and grammatically incorrect.